# Issue accessing "stored" values (smatr)

Tags: r

I am trying to access values from stored results from `sma` in package `smatr`. I have done this before and am using the same kind of code, but it's not working now and I can't figure out what the issue is. For example, in the following dataframe

```
test2 <- structure(list(x = 1:10, y = c(1L, 4L, 9L, 16L, 25L, 36L, 49L, 
64L, 81L, 100L)), .Names = c("x", "y"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))

    x   y
1   1   1
2   2   4
3   3   9
4   4   16
5   5   25
6   6   36
7   7   49
8   8   64
9   9   81
10  10  100
```

I am estimating the power function exponent (or slope on log-log transformed data) using

```
sma1 <- sma(log10(y)~log10(x), data=test2)
summary(sma1)
```

which yields an exponent/slope of 2 (there are unimportant errors thrown but it's just my example). I can see how to access the various components of the fit using

```
str(sma1)
```

I want to use these components for other things. For example, I can obtain the fitted minimum x value using `sma1$from` and can use this in calculations like

```
10^as.numeric(sma1$from)
```

However, when I try to access the fitted exponent/slope using

```
sma1$coef$'coef(SMA)'[2]
```

it returns `NULL` instead of a value of 2. I've used this successfully in the past, and can't understand why it's not working here. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: It should just be `sma1$coef[2]`

Comment: Thanks for the comment! However, that also returns "NULL". Note also that "sma1$coef" returns a matrix in which "coef(SMA)" is a column.

Comment: Is the other column `(Intercept)` ?  I can't download that package, for some reason.

Comment: Try `sma1$coef["coef(SMA)"]`

Comment: Thanks - but unfortunately, it's again "NULL".  :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to get it using `data.frame(sma1$coef)[2,2]`. They must have changed something in the new version (?).  Anyways, I hope this helps someone some time!